# Issue with running the Find method for ranges in two different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to run the Find method between two ranges in two different workbooks - If a value in the second range isn't found in the first range, then the data in the entire row to which the aforesaid cell belongs to should be copied from the second workbook and pasted in the first workbook. Each time I try to run my code I get runtime error #438 - Object doesn't support this property or method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Data_Transfer()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim FileCount As Byte, SheetCount As Byte, SheetFound As Byte
Dim SelectedBook As Workbook
Dim WkSh As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range, ChosenCell As Range, LookInRange As Range, LookAtRange As Range

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Files to Import Data", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(FileToOpen) Then 'Allows the user to click on the 'Cancel' button without it leading to an error
    
   For FileCount = 1 To UBound(FileToOpen)
        Set SelectedBook = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen(FileCount))

       'If a worksheet already exists for the month:
        For SheetCount = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetCount).Name = VBA.Replace(SelectedBook.Name, ".xls", "") Then
               SheetFound = 1
               Set WkSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetCount)
               WkSh.Activate
               MsgBox "A worksheet already exists for the selected month."
            
              'Check if there are any expenses missing for the month:
               Set LookInRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
               Set LookAtRange = SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
               For Each Cell In LookAtRange
                   Set ChosenCell = LookAtRange.Find(LookInRange.Cell, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                   If ChosenCell Is Nothing Then
                      ChosenCell.EntireRow.Copy WkSh.Range("A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1)
                   End If
                Next Cell
            End If
            If SheetFound = 1 Then: Exit Sub
        Next SheetCount
        
       'If a worksheet does not exist for the month:
        With ThisWorkbook
             .Worksheets.Add After:=Sheet11
             .ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Replace(SelectedBook.Name, ".xls", "")
             SelectedBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A23").CurrentRegion.Copy .ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
             SelectedBook.Close
             For Each Cell In .ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
                 If VBA.Left(Cell.Value, 1) = "*" Then
                    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
                 End If
             Next Cell
             .ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
        End With

    Next FileCount
    
End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: in which line do you get the error?

Comment: `SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)` here `Range("C2")` will be on the activesheet, not in `SelectedBook`  *Every time* you call `Range` or `Cells` you should be using a worksheet qualifier - without that your code will be prone to errors.

Comment: I am getting an error in this line; Set LookAtRange = SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row) . For some weird reason when I check the address for the range being captured in the immediate window it returns C7:C23, which is very strange as the starting cell for the range that I have specified is C23

Comment: well if `Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row` returns 7 and the range would be `C23:C7` that means Excel corrects it to `C7:C23` automatically. So these ranges are the same. So the issue is probably how you use `Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. The statement is SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23:C" & Range("C23").End(xlDown).Row) - I expect the range that the statement captures to be C23:C29, but instead it returns C23:C48 over and over again - I can't figure out why this happens as all cells from C24 onward are blank cells is the targeted sheet.

Comment: Note that `Range("C23").End(xlDown).Row` might not be in `SelectedBook.ActiveSheet` unless you specify that clearly `SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: Thank you Peh, the last bit of advice did the trick

Comment: @VarunKapur Wrote it as an answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always specify for **all** `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns` objects in which workbook and worksheet they are.

If you don't do that for example like here:

```
Set LookAtRange = SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
```

Then the first `Range` is in `SelectedBook.ActiveSheet` but the second may be or may be not! As long it is not defined you don't know:

```
Set LookAtRange = SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C23:C" & SelectedBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)
```

So make clear that `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns` objects are **always** fully referenced to a workbook/worksheet.